# Questions regarding CRUD operations

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sql-insert, crud

I am new to Android Studio and I am training to do a CRUD. When I try to insert a plant in the database, the message "Plant inserted" does not appear. Do you have an idea of ​​the problem ?
However, I display the message with the following code: `Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Plant inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

**Class PlantDataSource :**

```
public class PlantDataSource extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DatabasePlant dbPlant;

    public PlantDataSource(Context context) {
        super(context, "dbPlant", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String strReq = "CREATE TABLE tab_plant (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(strReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tab_plant");
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public boolean insertPlant (Plant plant) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", plant.getNom());
        long result = db.insert("tab_plant", null, values);
        boolean insert = result == -1 ? false : true;
        return insert;
    }

    public Cursor getAllPlants() {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tab_plant", null);
        return res;
    }

}
```

**Class ViewActivity :**

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PlantDataSource plantBdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        plantBdd = new PlantDataSource(this);
        viewAll();
    }

    public void viewAll() {
        Cursor res = plantBdd.getAllPlants();
        if (res.getCount() == 0) {
            showMessage("Error", "No plants to display");

        }
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            buffer.append("ID " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
            buffer.append("NAME " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
        }
        showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
    }

    public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

**Class AddActivity :**

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mPlantname;
    private Button mAddBtn;
    private  PlantDataSource plantBdd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        mPlantname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_plantname);
        mAddBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_addBtn);
        plantBdd = new PlantDataSource(this);
        addPlant();
    }

    public void addPlant() {
        mAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Plant plant = new Plant(mPlantname.getText().toString());
                    boolean isInserted = plantBdd.insertPlant(plant);
                    Log.i("***", String.valueOf(isInserted));
                    Log.i("xxx", String.valueOf(plant));

                    if (isInserted) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Plant inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: android studio is an IDE, meaning that it helps you to code and to develop your app. your question doesn't involve android studio as an IDE because you're directly asking about android, not about android-studio. please don't use the android studio tag if you're not asking about a feature of the IDE :)

Comment: Ok thank you but how can I do then to display this message?

Comment: are you getting any exception after insertion?

Comment: What does `Log.i("***", String.valueOf(isInserted));` print?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong within your code, could you try to use `TOAST.LENGTH_LONG` instead?

Comment: I have the same problem with TOAST.LENGTH_LONG